# Recognizing sender button control in click event

Tags: c#, winforms, custom-controls

I made a custom button that has a field named `Data`.

I add this button programatically during runtime to my winform and on adding I also define a click event for them. Well, Actually I only have one method and I subscribe the newly added buttons to this method.

But in the click event I want to access this `Data` field and show it as a message box, but it seems that my casting is not right:

```
    CustomButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Button button;
        if (sender is Button)
        {
            button = sender as Button;
        } 

        //How to access "Data" field in the sender button? 
        //button.Data  is not compiling!
    }
```

UPDATE:

I am sorry, I ment with "is not compiling" that `.Data` does not show up in intelisense...

Comment: You don't have to check whether `sender` is a `Button`, since the `as` keyword makes sure your variable is `null` if it can't cast your variable to the correct class.

Comment: This is not valid C# code so of course it won't work.  In general, a custom button control should override the OnClick method so it can implement its own custom click event behavior.

Comment: How did you try to access the 'Data' field?

Comment: It just didnt show up in intelisense...now that I cast it to `CustomButton` it does.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need to cast to the type of your custom class that has the Data field.

Something like:

```
YourCustomButton button = sender as YourCustomButton;
```

Comment: @Sean87 This answer addresses the problem of not being able to access the Data field but a better long term approach is to follow Hans's comment and override OnClick or possibly introduce custom events to make things a touch more typesafe - you currently rely on wiring up the customhandler (which is just a standard handler signature) to the right buttons. With a custom event you can be sure the wiring is correct.

Answer (score 3):

Assuming your custom button type is `CustomButton`, you should do this instead:

```
CustomButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e){
  CustomButton button = sender as CustomButton;
  if (button != null){
      // Use your button here
  } 
}
```

Answer (score 2):

If you dont want to set a variable the simple way to do is:

```
((CustomButton)sender).Click
```

or whatever you want.